# Split rangy range into two at specific offset

Tags: javascript, rangy

Ok, have been breaking my head on this one for the last few hours and hope there is somebody here with more experience with the rangy library. Let's say I have the following html:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum<note>that's latin</note> is a placeholder text</p>
<p>It is often used in graphic design<note>some other note</note></p>
```

And we've got a selection as indicated by the { and } characters:

```
<p>Lorem {Ipsum<note>that's latin</note> is a placeholder text</p>
<p>It is often used in graphic design<note>some other note</note>.}</p>
```

How could you split up the range into 3 range objects like this:

1. `Ipsum`
2. `is a placeholder text</p><p>It is often used in graphic design`
3. `.`

With the goal being to exclude a set of elements, in this case being `['note']`. I don't require a fully functional solution, **all I am looking for is a way to 'split' a rangy range up at a certain point in the range**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really specific to Rangy since you'll just use standard Range methods. Here's a simple function that will work on regular DOM ranges or Rangy ranges. It splits a range in two in a similar way to the [`splitText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text.splitText) method of text nodes: the original range's end boundary is moved to the split point and the function returns a new range starting at the split point and ending at the original range's original end boundary.

```
function splitRange(range, node, offset) {
    var newRange = range.cloneRange();
    newRange.setStart(node, offset);
    range.setEnd(node, offset);
    return newRange;
}
```

You could add this a method to all Rangy ranges if you like:

```
rangy.rangePrototype.splitRange = function(node, offset) {
    var newRange = this.cloneRange();
    newRange.setStart(node, offset);
    this.setEnd(node, offset);
    return newRange;
};
```

You could then split your example selection as follows:

```
// Get the <p> elements in the example HTML
var allPs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

var range1 = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

// Split after the first child of the first <p>
var range2 = range1.splitRange(allPs[0], 1); 

// Split after the first child of the second <p>
var range3 = range2.splitRange(allPs[1], 1);
```

`range1`, `range2` and `range3` are now as you require.

Comment: Thanks for your incredible library!!! Yeah, I just finished half an hour ago my own solution where I ended up looping over the DOM and creating new ranges from scratch which ended up working fine and just came here to post the relevant parts as an answer, but seems you beat me to it :) . Either way, one tiny tiny detail I would like to complain about, why doesn't the highlighter function accept ranges... would seem reasonable as the classapplier supports ranges. But oh well: detail.

Comment: @DavidMulder: There is a `highlightRanges()` method.

Comment: *feels like hiding in a dark corner* ... I am sure I scrolled through the file 3 or 4 times looking for that function and didn't see one... my bad, my bad, incredible job once again!!

Comment: @DavidMulder: Not really your fault that I haven't got round to documenting it yet :)